# Django SuspiciousFileOperation: But Paths are correct

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-pipeline

Fellow SOs:

From one day to the other day, without making any changes *other than installing windows updates*, I get this error message:

```
The joined path (C:\Users\X\Y\Z\data\static_files\admin\css\autocomplete.css) is located outside of the base path component (C:\Users\X\Y\Z\data\static_files\)
```

I do know what the error means in general, but as the file is obviously within the base_dir, I dont get what is wrong.

The error pops up on every page except for `/admin`.

**Settings:**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../data/media_files/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../data/static_files/')
```

The setup still works fine on my Mac, but fails on Windows 10 since the last update.

Edit: I am using django-pipeline 1.7.0

Any ideas?